# Savaztky Golay filtering problem on LAI (Leaf Area Index ) time series in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, filtering, sentinel2

I'm new to Python and I'm hoping someone can help me understand my problem.

In fact, I'm working on data (count, min, max, sdt) extracted from a one-year LAI (Leaf Index Area) time series. My aim is to perform smoothing on the mean of the maximum LAI of my time series for segment_id (plot), using linear interpolation while applying a Savitzky-Golay filter. The results I obtained, even after adjusting the window and polyorder parameters, were not satisfactory.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import numpy as np

# import data
file_path = '......../LAI.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path).drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1)

# convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

# sort by segment_id
df = df.sort_values(by=['segment_id'], ascending=True)

# convert date to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%Y%m%d')
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.dayofyear

# calculate mean by each segment_id 

mean_max = df.groupby(['segment_id']).mean()

# Define segment_ids 

segment_ids = list(range(0,1)) # plot only 2 segment_ids
# Iterate over each segment_id in segment_ids
for segment_id in segment_ids:
    df_filtered = df[df['segment_id'] == segment_id].copy()
    
     # linear interpolation
    
    x = df_filtered['date']
    y = df_filtered['mean']

    # remove negative values max
    y = y.mask(y < 0)

    if y.isna().all():  # if all values are NaN, skip this segment_id
        continue

    xnew = np.linspace(40, 400)

    nan_indices = y.isna()
    yinterp = np.interp(xnew, x[~nan_indices], y[~nan_indices])
    
    # savgol filter
    yinterp1 = savgol_filter(yinterp, 15, 3, mode ='interp', cval = 1) # window size 15, polynomial order 3
  
    
   plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))    
    plt.plot(x, y, 'o',label='data')
    plt.plot(xnew, yinterp1, '-', label='linear')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.xlabel('Day of year')
    plt.ylabel('Mean of Max LAI')
    plt.show()

Both images with and without smoothing:
```

[image: Both images with and without smoothing]

I'd like to obtain a smoothed curve along the data points, as shown in the image, by adjusting the filter parameters:

[image: I'd like to obtain a smoothed curve along the data points, as shown in the image, by adjusting the filter parameters.]

[My problem fixed it's liked to data sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Ezy.png)

I just changed this `x = df_filtered['date'].sort_index() y = df_filtered['mean'].sort_index()/1000`

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. You say you want to smooth your raw data with a smoothed curve along the data points using S-G filtering, but the orange lines you show look like an incredibly bad approximation to the integral under them. Apart from the odd outlier your data don't look that bad and any old cubic spline will do for a nice smooth curve approximately joining the dots. Joining all the dots with straight lines would be much better than what you have now. It's a shame  there is such a big gap in the observations 180d-240d on the rising curve though. There may be detail lost

Comment: Could you post a link to your dataset in order to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your comment, exactly, I'd just like to connect the points to get a better curve. Indeed, for the reason of the gap between 180d and 240d, I used the linear interpolation. Finally, the result did not work.

Comment: Here my dataset link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TEqCyFg3W-DPFv_mspnigPbKmDe8z8II/view?usp=sharing